# Regular expression to extract elements from a string

Tags: regex, perl

In my perl program, I am having a string in `$new` which is of variable length. Following are some of the instances:

```
$new = "sdf / wer / wewe / dfg";
$new = "lkjz / dfgr / wdvf";
$new = "asdfe";
```

How do I extract the elements seperated by `/` into an array using Regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `split` function, which takes as arguments a pattern to split on, the string to split, and optionally the number of times to split.

```
$new    = "sdf / wer / wewe / dfg";
@values = split(" / ", $new );
```

Comment: That was so simple and I was thinking of regular expressions! :P
Thanks man!

Comment: @rad, Well, the first arg to `split` is a regular expression :) Incidentally, I prefer not hiding that fact. I'd use `split(qr{ / }, $new)` or `split(qr{\s*/\s*/}, $new)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a fixed delimiter, then a regex isn't necessarily the best option.  The split function is a better choice:

```
my @items = split " / ", $new;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what characters can be in the elements, but assuming they can contain anything but slashes, this will extract them for you. It also excludes any leading or trailing whitespace and empty fields.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @new = (
  "  sdf / wer / wewe / dfg  ",
  "  sdf / dfgr / wdvf  ",
  "  asdfe  ",
  "  first field / second field  ",
  "  a / b / c / d / e / f  ",
);

for (@new) {
  my @fields = m|[^/\s](?:[^/]*[^/\s])?|g;
  printf "(%s)\n",  join ', ', map "'$_'", @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
('sdf', 'wer', 'wewe', 'dfg')
('sdf', 'dfgr', 'wdvf')
('asdfe')
('first field', 'second field')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```